# Sort envelope in each category

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm having a problem in sorting categories and envelopes together. I first create the sorting of categories and it works. Then I create next the envelope. When I drag one of the envelope, the data goes on top and when I drop it the category id is wrong. Every time I drag and drop different envelope in any category, there category id is the same. I can't get the exact category id. I don't know how to implement both functions in one page. I don't know how to sort envelopes in each category. :/

The sort codes is based from here: http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/

Here are my codes: http://pastebin.com/UKZvz0SU

The views and urls are working. My problem is I can't sort the envelope in there category. I can't get the exact category for them.

Sample image of the page:

[image]